# How to add seventh color to orderInput in shinyjqui

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinyjqui

The `orderInput()` function from the `shinyjqui` package utilizes six pre-defined Bootstrap button classes to style the items it displays. These styles can be specified using the `item_class` parameter. For further details, [refer to the documentation](https://yang-tang.github.io/shinyjqui/articles/orderInput.html).

I try to add additional classes, the `orderInput()` function, that appears to be designed to only accept the six predefined Bootstrap button classes (`default`, `primary`, `success`, `info`, `warning`, `danger`).

I this possible?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
            .grey { background-color: grey; color: white; }
           ")
    )
  ),
  
  uiOutput("custom_orderInput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$custom_orderInput <- renderUI({
    
    tagList(
      orderInput('default', 'default', items = 1:3, item_class = 'default'),
      orderInput('primary', 'primary', items = 1:3, item_class = 'primary'),
      orderInput('success', 'success', items = 1:3, item_class = 'success'),
      orderInput('info', 'info', items = 1:3, item_class = 'info'),
      orderInput('warning', 'warning', items = 1:3, item_class = 'warning'),
      orderInput('danger', 'danger', items = 1:3, item_class = 'danger'),
      orderInput('grey', 'grey', items = 7:9, item_class = 'grey')
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: Implemented the suggestion by @Stéphane Laurent:**

changed `.grey > button` with `#grey > .btn`
removed `library(shinyjs)` and `useShinyjs()`
and increase 50 to 75

The orderInput() function from shinyjqui is designed with Bootstrap button classes in mind. If the function doesn't natively support custom classes, you might need to apply a hack to get around this.

You have defined the .grey class correctly, but if orderInput() isn't directly supporting custom classes, one method would be to use JavaScript to modify the class attribute of the rendered HTML elements after they've been created by Shiny.

Perhaps you could try this workaround to fix your issue:

Include a `shinyjs` function to run custom JS.
Run a small JS script to add your custom class to the desired elements after they're rendered. Now you can modify your existing code to achieve this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
            .grey { background-color: grey; color: white; }
           ")
    )
  ),
  
  uiOutput("custom_orderInput"),
  
  # Add a JS script to add the 'grey' class to the appropriate elements
  tags$script(
    HTML("
         $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
           setTimeout(function(){
             $('#grey > .btn').addClass('grey');
           }, 75);
         });
         ")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$custom_orderInput <- renderUI({
    
    tagList(
      orderInput('default', 'default', items = 1:3, item_class = 'default'),
      orderInput('primary', 'primary', items = 1:3, item_class = 'primary'),
      orderInput('success', 'success', items = 1:3, item_class = 'success'),
      orderInput('info', 'info', items = 1:3, item_class = 'info'),
      orderInput('warning', 'warning', items = 1:3, item_class = 'warning'),
      orderInput('danger', 'danger', items = 1:3, item_class = 'danger'),
      orderInput('grey', 'grey', items = 7:9, item_class = 'default') # Use 'default' as a placeholder
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This way utilizing the `shinyjs` package to integrate custom JS. After the Shiny app connects, the JavaScript waits for a short time (50ms in this case, but you can adjust as needed) and then adds the .grey class to the button elements inside the `.grey` parent. We also set the item_class to 'default' as a placeholder, which will be overridden by our JS.

Comment: Nice. But you don't use **shinyjs** here, it is useless.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, however, I just thought this could aid you or anyone else that could potentially experience it as a last resort perhaps a workaround like this could be useful for you're project =)

Comment: Thank you very much. But now the grey item class should have grey background. But item 7,8,9 remain white like default. ?

Comment: @TarJae Replace `'.grey > button'` with `'#grey > .btn'`. You may also need to increase the 50ms.

Comment: Thx @StéphaneLaurent. Same behaviour. White buttons. No grey. Hmmmh?

Comment: @TarJae Works for me. Strange. I changed 50 to 500.

Comment: that is really strange I will shutdown and restart.

Comment: @TarJae And don't include **shinyjs** package neither `useShinyjs()`. If that doesn't work increase 500.

Comment: Yeah. Now I got it. Thank you very much @StéphaneLaurent. But why we have to set the 50 to 500?!

Comment: @TarJae Because these elements do not exist 50ms after Shiny is connected.  They are not rendered yet. I will show you a better way wait.

Answer (score 3):

@0xe1λ7r's answer is nice. That said, you can avoid the use of `setTimeout` which implies a choice of the delay, and use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead:

```r
    HTML("
         $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
              var $itemGroup = $('#grey > .btn');
              if($itemGroup.length) {
                $itemGroup.addClass('grey');
                clearInterval(interval);
              }
            }, 10);
         });
   ")
```

With this code, the existence of the items group is checked each period of 10 ms after the Shiny connection, and once it is detected the new class is added and then the code is destroyed.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your time and contribution to solving the problem.